# WebSphere REST service error "FFDC Incident emitted"

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, websphere

I have a Java EE application with a pair of SOAP webservices that are working.  I am attempting to add a REST call to the same application; I'm following a page from IBM developerWorks [A simple RESTful implementation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1305_gunderson/1305_gunderson.html)

They give lines in the following form in their web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>a.b.c.RSApplication</servlet-name>
</servlet>
```

Note: there is no servlet-class tag within servlet; my RAD xml validator is bothered by this and gives me an error.  They do map the same class for servlet-mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>a.b.c.RSApplication</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The RSApplication class extends Application, which is not a Servlet extension, and looks like this:

```
public class RSApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // Resources
        classes.add(a.b.c.RS.class);

        // Providers

        return classes;
    }
}
```

And the RS class:

```
@Path("/rabbit")
@Stateless
public class RS {
    @POST
    public Response s(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Object o) {
        return sImpl(uriInfo, o);
    }

    @GET
    public Response s2(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Object o) {
        return sImpl(uriInfo, o);
    }

    private Response sImpl(UriInfo uriInfo, Object o) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

All of this follows the same format as their example.  I ran it on WebSphere within RAD on my machine, but the server won't run my application with the servlet-class tag missing from my web.xml.   So I go back to that and put in the RS class.  I configured SoapUI to send a request to `http://localhost:9094/contextroot/rest/rabbit`, 
and get back "Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet [a.b.c.RS]: not a servlet class"

The statement on the web page is that the "JAX-RS aware servlet container" allows the above servlet name and "... maps the ... pattern to [this] class, and the ... servlet container automatically connects the dots so that references to the ... pattern invoke the appropriate resource class" (RS in my example).

The only other difference I see is that they have JSON being consumed and produced and I don't yet have any.  I would expect a different error if that was the problem.

Can someone point me to how to configure this so that this magic dot-connecting can take place, or even just how to configure the servlet class in web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your web.xml like this way:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>a.b.c.RSApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use xml configuration, then you can modify you application subclass and use annotation `@ApplicationPath("rest")` like:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RSApplication extends Application{}
```

This should resolve your issue.